# Python - too many values to unpack while looking for a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a message that `file not found` when it doesn't match the `file_name*.txt` pattern in specific directory.

When calling the script with `file_name*.txt` argument, all works fine. While entering invalid name `file_*.txt` throws:

```
File "etl.py", line 14, in main
path, file = file_path.get_source_file_path()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Why is this happening?

```
import fnmatch
import os

class FilePrep:
    def __init__(self, path_dir, file_name):
        self.path = path_dir
        self.file_name = file_name

    def get_source_file_path(self):
        source_file = []

        for file_name in os.listdir(self.path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, self.file_name):
                source_file.append(file_name)
        try:            
            source_file_name = str(source_file[0])
        except IndexError:
            return "file not found"
        
        file_path = os.path.join(self.path, source_file_name)
        return file_path, source_file_name
```

main.py

```
import file_prep
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
import pandas
import sys

def main():

    dir = sys.argv[1]
    file_input = sys.argv[2]

    #python3 etl.py /home/user/projects/python/folder/ file_name*.xml
    file_path = file_prep.FilePrep(dir, file_input)

    path, file = file_path.get_source_file_path()
    print(path)
```

Comment: In which line there is the error?

Comment: Presumably, because **you** did `return "file not found"`. Generally, returning little messages like that is not a good practice. You should raise an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line in `main.py`:

```py
path, file = file_path.get_source_file_path()
```

here you are unpacking the return value of `get_source_file_path()` into two variables. This works fine if the file exists (because you actually return two values) but does not when the file does not exist since you only return one value `return "file not found"`.

To fix this I would raise an error instead of returning a string message in case of failure. Your code can become:

```py
import fnmatch
import os

class FileNotFoundError(Exception):
    pass

class FilePrep:
    def __init__(self, path_dir, file_name):
        self.path = path_dir
        self.file_name = file_name

    def get_source_file_path(self):
        source_file = []

        for file_name in os.listdir(self.path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, self.file_name):
                source_file.append(file_name)
        try:            
            source_file_name = str(source_file[0])
        except IndexError:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"file {self.file_name} not found")
        
        file_path = os.path.join(self.path, source_file_name)
        return file_path, source_file_name
```

```py
import file_prep
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
import pandas
import sys

def main():

    dir = sys.argv[1]
    file_input = sys.argv[2]

    #python3 etl.py /home/user/projects/python/folder/ file_name*.xml
    file_path = file_prep.FilePrep(dir, file_input)

    try:
        path, file = file_path.get_source_file_path()
        print(path)
    except file_prep.FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: got an error `"source_file_name" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable`

Comment: Error message needs to be changed to this raise FileNotFoundError(f"file {self.file_name} not found")

Comment: @joshackland is correct!  I have fixed the code

Comment: Thanks Matteo! Could you elaborate a bit more on why using seperate `FileNotFoundError` class?

Comment: If someone else were going to run that function and they received an `IndexError` it's not clear what that means. Seeing `FileNotFoundError` clearly states that the file you are searching for is unavailable.

Comment: It is not necessary but it is usefull to be cerain of only catching the errors you have manually raised and not any other errors that may occur in the code. You can easilly just omit the try and re-raise part and catch the original error in main but for bigger porjects this will lead to coe that is harder to debug, therefore it is a best-practice to create custom exception classes and raise those. Here some reading https://towardsdatascience.com/python-writing-custom-exceptions-is-easier-than-you-might-think-14df327e503e

Comment: Great thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers somewhat got it the wrong way, saying in case of failure, "only one" value is returned. While that's true, it doesn't explain why the error message says there are "too **many** values to unpack", since 1 is not more than 2. The reason is that that **one** value is a string, which, due to to the multi-assignment, will be treated as an **iterable**. Since it has 14 characters, that's 14 values, and that's too many.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this following line:

```
except IndexError:
    return "file not found"
```

When you hit that `except` condition your `return` from your function call returns only one variable, that string. You could modify your condition to do the following:

```
except IndexError:
    source_file_name = "file not found"
```

However this won't work as you try to use this file name later on, a better approach would be to `raise` an error properly as shown in this answer by Matteo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632648/6817835).

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function here, it's expected that two values will be returned

```
path, file = file_path.get_source_file_path()
```

When an exception occurs here, only one value is being returned which is causing the error

```
try:            
    source_file_name = str(source_file[0])
except IndexError:
    return "file not found"
```

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Make it so only one value is expected to be returned and you modify the return at the bottom to only pass one value
2. You modify the exception so it returns two values